# Algorithm name?: Concatenate the ranges returned by a function applied to each element of a range

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, stl-algorithm

Maybe I'm missing something. Is there a function in `<algorithm>` that does this? If not, what would you call it? It seems like a particular flavor of transform-reduce that is so specific it needs a name:

```
template <typename Iter, typename OutIter, typename Fn>
void transformed_concatenated(Iter beg, Iter end, OutIter out, Fn f) {
    for (; beg != end; ++beg) {
        for (auto& x : f(*beg)) {
            *out++ = std::move(x);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

That is, if I do

```
const std::vector<int> input { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
const auto f = [](int n) { return std::vector<int>(n, n * 2 + 1); };
std::vector<int> result;
transformed_concatenated(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(result), f);
```

I would get `3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7`.

Something like it could be done with `std::transform_reduce`, but I feel like it loses something.

Comment: Could you add a textual description of what the code is supposed to do (in addition to the code)? I don't like relying on interpretation of someone's code to determine what they intend.

Comment: This is sometimes called `flatMap`.

Comment: In addition to a textual explanation, it would also be helpful to add an example of input and desired output for the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the ranges and views introduced in C++20, you could write:

```
std::ranges::copy(input 
                  | std::views::transform(f) 
                  | std::views::join, 
                  std::back_inserter(result));
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mcf4va7Y5).

---

Note that your function `f` is incorrect. It needs to be

```
const auto f = [](int n) { return std::vector<int>(n, n); };
                                               // ^____^
```

to get the desired output `1 2 2 3 3 3`. If you use braces to construct the vector, you'll get a vector of 2 elements, both with the value `n`, and the output will be `1 1 2 2 3 3`.

Comment: Nice! With that in mind, I guess `transform_join` would be a good name for my old-fashioned non-ranges version.

Comment: @Ben Yes, that would be a good name for the function.